# Is it possible to add a default URL parameter inside a theme template_XYZ function?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view with a pulldown menu within an exposed form. I want to set that URL parameter to a default value based on the currentLanguage() of the session. Is there a way to edit the URL parameters that a View can see within a custom module or the theme's `template_` functions?

Answer (score 1):

Within a custom module, it is possible to use the [hook_views_pre_view hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/8.2.x). You can alter the `$args` array passed as parameter, in order to add or remove arguments.

Comment: Thanks. Strangely my new function `MYMODULE_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args)` in MYMODULE.module is ignored even after a full cache reset.

Comment: @Nic, yes it is strange. I just made some testing on a vanilla D8 site, and MYMODULE_views_pre_view(...) is called. Maybe a caching issue...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this to get it working:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-BLAH-page-1e' && 
        $form_id ="views_exposed_form") {
    $request = \Drupal::request();
     // check that no URL param is already set
      if (!$request->get('MYEXPOSEDFIELDID', NULL)) { 
        // reference to user input object (for editing)
        $input = &$form_state->getUserInput();
        $input['MYEXPOSEDFIELDID'] = NEWVALUE;
      }
    }
```